# How to manage different projects in git?

Tags: git

I have some projects and use git for them.
Now I want to do another project from existing ones.
They might have shared code and different code for each one.
What is best approach for this?
Fork or branching?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Submodules are great when you have project dependent on other projects and you want to share code. The other projects can evolve independently and you can sync with them from time to tim
e. It's slightly advanced but very useful once you start using this feature.